# How to make a query for Big Brother nomination?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, left-join, case

I have a table with three columns:

- Participant.
- First vote participant (two points).
- Second vote participant (one point).

```
CREATE TABLE `voting` (
  `participant` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstVote` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `secondVote` varchar(11) NOT NULL
)
```

I am stuck trying to write a query that returns two columns: the participant and the number of points they received.

Example:

| participant | firstVote | secondVote |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Jane | Holland |
| Jane | Mary | Holland |
| Donatella | Mary | Jane |
| Holland | Mary | Jane |

Query:

| participant | votesReceived |
| --- | --- |
| Mary | 6 |
| Jane | 4 |
| Holland | 2 |
| Donatella | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self `LEFT` join and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT v1.participant,
       COALESCE(
         SUM(
           2 * (v1.participant = v2.firstVote) + 
           (v1.participant = v2.secondVote)
         ), 
         0
       ) AS votesReceived
FROM voting v1 LEFT JOIN voting v2
ON v1.participant IN (v2.firstVote, v2.secondVote)
GROUP BY v1.participant
ORDER BY votesReceived DESC;
```

Or:

```
SELECT v1.participant,
       SUM(
         CASE v1.participant  
           WHEN v2.firstVote THEN 2
           WHEN v2.secondVote THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS votesReceived
FROM voting v1 LEFT JOIN voting v2
ON v1.participant IN (v2.firstVote, v2.secondVote)
GROUP BY v1.participant
ORDER BY votesReceived DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/c3nD9UeY).